# Where is the .app program? (Mac OS X and iOS)

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos

I'm trying to find the .app file in my project folders but I can't find it. As I remember it was just to go into the build folder in the project folder and the .app file should be there but now I don't have a build folder in those app.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you remove the build folder by accident?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Xcode: expand Products then, right click on your app and from the menu click on Show on Finder or Reveal on Finder.

Comment: Thanks! :) I was so used to have the build folder in the project folder where the xcode project is

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode 4, build products are stored by default in:

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-lotsofrandomchars/Build/Products/
```

Answer (score 1):

If you've upgraded to Xcode 4, things have changed. Click Product/Archive to build a release version of your app, then Window/Organizer, and select the Archives pane. Select the archive you just built, then click the "share" button towards the top right.